# How to find currently opened ImapFolder

Tags: mailkit

I want to close currently opened folder before running any Folder operation Rename/Move/Delete/Create. I don't keep the reference to the currently opened ImapFolder. Is there are a way to search ImapClient for the currently opened folder?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You need to track it by keeping a reference to the currently selected folder.